# How can I play multiple frequencies of sound at once in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, runtime, naudio

I am trying to make a simple program that plays different frequencies of sound based on what colors are put in from of a camera. I need to play multiple sine waves at once in sound. Console.Beep works for just one frequency. I also need it to be generated at run time. I have tried using the .wav generator in NAudio but I am not sure how the .wav format works in that context to create multiple frequencies. Converting a random byte array to a .wav just shows static because of samples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use the SignalGenerator to create sine-wave waveforms with the desired frequencies. Then mix them together. See here about NAudio mixing: https://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio. (This site has a lot more resources and information about NAudio, which could be worth checking out...)

Answer (score 0):

By default, c# runs a single thread. This means that there is only one thing happening at any one time inside the code. Therefore, you need multithreading for simultaneous actions. 
 Also,m I'd look into delegates in C#, that could call multiple methods from a single event. This will allow you to trigger multiple actions from a single trigger.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/